# How to create Modular RESTful web service with Spring Boot and Spring Data Rest

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

Currently I have a Spring Web Application built using Spring Boot that exposes some restful endpoints using Spring Data REST.

What I can't figure out is how to allow my web application to load new entities, repositories and controllers at application start up. I would want to be able to build new classes into a separate jar and place it into a plugins folder and have their annotations scanned just like the new classes were part of the main application.

An example would be having a jar with two components:

1. A class annotated with @Entity that directly maps to a database table and having a CrudRepository. It would be declared in the same package as the entities in the main project.
2. An interface for that entity that is annotated with @RepositoryRestResouce. It would be declared in the same package as the repositories in the main project.

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason it would not work.

Did you check that your component-scan is actually scanning your new classes ?